# Biqquery quota limits on UDF

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, user-defined-functions

**Concurrent rate limit for queries that contain user-defined functions (UDFs):** 6 concurrent queries, including both interactive and batch queries. Interactive queries that contain UDFs count toward the concurrent rate limit for interactive queries.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#queries

My question. 
The limit is 6 concurrent queries containing UDF. Is this limits means not more then 6 different queries containing UDF or one query contain UDF can't run Concurrently more then 6 time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is six queries at once. It doesn't matter what the queries are or whether they contain the same user-defined function text.

Comment: what if I need to execute more then six UDF queries?

Comment: try running in batch mode - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#interactive-batch

Comment: Or use [standard SQL UDFs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions), which should be less restrictive about how many you can run at once.

Comment: I am using standard SQL UDF only. Is there no restriction on Standard SQL UDF?

Comment: The published limit is still six concurrent queries, though in practice the concurrency will not be limited unless you are running very CPU-intensive UDFs.

Comment: I have a Standard SQL UDF query and I need to run that query 1000 time concurrently. is it possible?

Comment: No, and this applies to [non-UDF queries as well](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy): "Concurrent rate limit for interactive queries under on-demand pricing: 50 concurrent queries. Queries that return cached results, or queries configured using the dryRun property, do not count against this limit."

Comment: is there any way to increase this quota?

Comment: Mikhail's suggestion of batch mode is a good one. Or you can run a few larger queries that do more work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142746/discussion-between-manoj-kumar-and-elliott-brossard).

Comment: A better option would be talking to a [cloud sales representative](https://cloud.google.com/contact/) :) While you'll find engineers like me here on StackOverflow, cloud salespeople are better at helping to understand and make suggestions about requirements.

Comment: Thanks Elliot for cloud sales connect. I filled the form and waiting for the mail or call from their side. One more question please. If I will use the batch mode then there is no restriction on concurrency for standard SQL UDF queries?

Comment: I believe that using batch mode will rate-limit queries (including those with UDFs) appropriately, so there's nothing specific to UDFs to worry about, but whoever contacts you from Cloud Support might know more.