# Bigquery Standard SQL UDF concurrent means?

Tags: java, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I have posted a question on - [Biqquery quota limits on UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631632/biqquery-quota-limits-on-udf/43632039#43632039)

This question is related to this limit only but information required is different. I want to know that is the meaning of concurrent. Let say I trigger a query like Query1 that that query execute till 10 sec. After 20 milli second I will execute same query and that also execute till 10 sec. So can I say that both queries are different?

I am executing standard sql query with UDF which has 6 concurrent query limit. But I executed this standard sql UDF query on 20 parallel threads with the help of java. I didn't get any concurrent limit exception. I was tring to test this limit as I have to execute this query on 1000 threads.

Comment: I don't see how this question different from your other one. Elliot also wrote in a comment - _"[In standard SQL] The published limit is still six concurrent queries, though in practice the concurrency will not be limited unless you are running very CPU-intensive UDFs."_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Biqquery quota limits on UDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631632/biqquery-quota-limits-on-udf)